# Locking a table with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a table that I want to run a pretty long running migration on (~20 mins). During this time the contents of the table should not be changed at all. However, the rails frontend to this table (and many others) will remain up while the migration is running and there is a very real chance that someone will try to modify some data (it's fine if that call ends up throwing an error though).

We use MySQL and allow for 10 connections in our connection pool. Am I right in assuming that it is not enough to wrap this migration in a transaction, but that I would have to lock down the table itself as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to make sure no modifications at all happen to the table, the safest thing is to lock the table on a mysql level.

If, however, you just want to make sure that no competing writes/overwrites happen, you could also use [optimistic locking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#optimistic-locking). One thing to mention is, that this could mean, the import script will complain and some saves might fail, because between read and write the front end might have changed the record.

Assuming that would be okay and you could just repeat those individual writes, this is how it would work:

By convention you have to add an integer column called `lock_version` to the table in question and then you're magically set in the way we love from rails.

There's a bit more to it which I encourage you to read about in the [linked documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#optimistic-locking) and that we can discuss in the comments if you like.